# How to return Media Type as a XML in Spring REST Service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-roo

Hi I am working with Spring REST Web Services. I want to return Media Type as a XML. When i am using `@ResponseBody` it automatically returns JSON. I have read many blogs they are very confusing and they are using JaxB. I need some simple and step wise solution. Any solution based in same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From Spring ref guide (chap 17):

> Supported method return types
>
> - ...
> - If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is written to the response HTTP body. The return value will be converted
>     to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters.

To return an XML I see two options:

1. Return an String and you should convert the Media Type to XML manually
2. Return a `ResponseEntity` instance. To learn more http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody